# Telerik Kendo Grid for ASP.Net Core MVC dataSource.read Action Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple grid that I am trying to load in my Razor page, but I am getting an error when the page loads. I cannot find a resource that can help with this error.

I did notice that the second line of the error (see full error below) `Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase<TCrudOperationBuilder>.Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)` is indicating that the Action method is expecting an Object to be passed after the controllerName, but all the documentation indicates that only the Action and Controller names are needed. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my **Error**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase<TCrudOperationBuilder>.Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
   at AspNetCore.Views_ExcludeCCNs_Index.<>c.<ExecuteAsync>b__9_3(CrudOperationBuilder read) in C:\Dev\2018.12.07\Prototypes\DBManagementUI\DBManagementUI\Views\ExcludeCCNs\Index.cshtml:line 19
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.AjaxDataSourceBuilderBase<TModel, TDataSourceBuilder>.Read(Action<CrudOperationBuilder> configurator)
   at AspNetCore.Views_ExcludeCCNs_Index.<>c.<ExecuteAsync>b__9_1(DataSourceBuilder<ExcludeCCN> dataSource) in C:\Dev\2018.12.07\Prototypes\DBManagementUI\DBManagementUI\Views\ExcludeCCNs\Index.cshtml:line 17
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder<T>.DataSource(Action<DataSourceBuilder<T>> configurator)
   at AspNetCore.Views_ExcludeCCNs_Index.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Dev\2018.12.07\Prototypes\DBManagementUI\DBManagementUI\Views\ExcludeCCNs\Index.cshtml:line 14
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here is my **Kendo Grid**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DBManagementUI.Models.ExcludeCCN>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("ExcludeCCNs", "ExcludeCCNs"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(product => product.CCN);
    })
)
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class ExcludeCCNsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CWPAdminContext _context;
        public ExcludeCCNsController(CWPAdminContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        private IEnumerable<ExcludeCCN> GetExcludeCCNs()
        {
            return _context.ExcludeCCN.Take(100).ToList();
        }

        public IActionResult ExcludeCCNs([DataSourceRequest] 
        DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetExcludeCCNs().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Here is my **Startup.cs file**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ARCHContext>();
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CWPAdminContext>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                         .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseKendo(env);
```

Comment: The kendo code seems ok to me. Are you able to 'route' to the specific controller method or does the exception occur beforehand? Also does ExcludeCCN have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: The exception occurs before the controller method is ever called. Are you asking about my ExcludeCCN model? I am using Entity Framework Core and the ExcludeCCN Entity only has properties, there is no constructor for that class.

Comment: Although I get another exception, your controller has to have to an empty constructor. Add one and let us know if it works.

Comment: That did not change the exception. I got the same one after adding an empty constructor. I have read in other places that the return statement when returning Json should add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`  to the end. Then my return statement would look like this: `return Json(GetExcludeCCNs().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`. However, JsonRequestBehavior is deprecated in ASP.Net Core 1.0 so this cannot be used.